# Tracking multilevel actions in Piwik

Tags: matomo

My current understanding of campaigns in Piwik is that you can check how many users went from `point A` to `point B`.

But what if,

I want to find out how many users traversed from `point A` to `point B` to `point C`.

P.S: Incase anyone is confused, `A to B to C` is not `A to C`

Or is there any other functionality apart from piwik campaigns that provides the same thing?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://piwik.org/docs/users-flow/ https://plugins.piwik.org/UsersFlow

Comment: @LukasWinkler this is a paid version. Any workaround available from existing set of free tools?